# How can I check for a maximum number of elements with a specific class?

Tags: jquery, addclass, toggleclass

Im looking for the best way of doing something. I have a list with different categories. All the list item are clickable. I want the user to pick between 1 and 3 items.

When he clicks on something, Im adding a selected class on the li. When he click again on the same item, it remove the class (ToggleClass() )

Im wrapping that whole thing in a condition to count how many items have the selected class. Here's a Fiddle of where Im at now:

http://jsfiddle.net/nfQum/1/

My problem is that when you have selected 3 items, you can't "deselect one" cause my if statement is blocking it. What's the solution here ? (I also feel that this code is really not the best way of doing it)

Code (same as on Fidlle above)

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li class="chooseCategory16"><a onclick="test(16); return false;" href="#">test1</a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

JS

```
function test(number) {
  if ( $("li.selected").length <= 2) {
     if( $("li.chooseCategory"+ number +"").hasClass("selected")) {                
         $("li.chooseCategory"+ number +"").removeClass("selected");
     } else {
         $("li.chooseCategory"+ number +"").addClass("selected");
     }
   }
}
```

​

Comment: Could you please also add the **relevant** code here on SO?

Comment: Well, obviously you want to check if the maximum is reached _only_ if the clicked element _does not_ have the class already.

Comment: Added the code in the question as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to avoid inline javascript, so I've made it a bit more jQuerified.

http://jsfiddle.net/nfQum/7/

```
$('li.category').on('click',function(){
    var $this = $(this); //store you jquery object - this referes to the element clicked

    if ($this.hasClass("selected")) {
        $this.removeClass("selected");
    }else{
        if ($('li.selected').length !== 3){
            $this.addClass("selected");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I took your answer, can you please check below?

Answer (score 2):

Following the principle that you let people get on with their tasks (get the ui out of the way) if they are doing it right, and intercepting errors with clear information about what the problem is, and how to solve it, I would propose the same method you are using, but use a modal window to inform the user when they have selected too many items.

Alternatively, you could use context sensitive message near the list if you can do it in a way that the user will definitely see. You don't want to leave them unaware of the problem.

```
function test(number) {
    // always run this to allow removal of class when too many are selected
    if ($("li.chooseCategory" + number + "").hasClass("selected")) {
        $("li.chooseCategory" + number + "").removeClass("selected");
    } else {
        // move this condition inside the else
        if ($("li.selected").length <= 2) {
            $("li.chooseCategory" + number + "").addClass("selected");
        } else {
            // add notification of problem and how to solve
            // a modal window, or context sensitive help here
            alert('you can only select 3 - please deselct one!')
        }
    }
}​
```

### Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/nfQum/2/

Answer (score 2):

First: it's a very good practice to avoid using inline javascript. jQuery makes it really easy to bind events to elements, rather than having javascript in your markup. My example shows how to bind events to those items based on their container. Because it uses a delegate event - one where a single event is bound to the container that then checks for context - rather than binding events to each item, it also improves performance.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/nate/nfQum/5/

```
$('.choose').on('click', 'li', function (event) {
        // save a reference to the container ul
    var $container = $(event.delegateTarget),
        // save a reference to the li that was clicked
        $element = $(event.currentTarget);

    // if the li has the selected class...
    if ($element.hasClass('selected')) {
        // ...remove it!
        $element.removeClass('selected');
    } else {
        // if it doesn't have the selected class, check whether
        // the container has fewer than three children with the
        // selected class
        if ($container.children('.selected').length < 3) {
            // if so, go ahead and add selected to this item
            $element.addClass('selected')
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function test(number) {
    if ($("li.selected").length <= 2)
        {
            if($("li.chooseCategory"+ number +"").hasClass("selected")) {

                $("li.chooseCategory"+ number +"").removeClass("selected");
            }else {
                $("li.chooseCategory"+ number +"").addClass("selected");
            }
        } else {
            if( $(event.target).parent().hasClass("selected") ) {
                 $(event.target).parent().removeClass("selected");
            }                
        }
}
```

The else part will deselect the selected li. http://jsfiddle.net/uznbu/1/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inline handlers and do:

```
$('ul li a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('li')[$('li.selected').length>2?'removeClass':'toggleClass']('selected');
});
```

​
[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pWdQB/1/)

Comment: Perhaps explain what you're doing? Based on the question, op doesn't seem all that familiar with jQuery.

Comment: @Jack - A little mystery in life is always good, and it gives the OP a chance to use Google to figure it out, and we all need to support the google machine.